# Как стилизовать option select?

Tags: html, css

Не получается применить шрифт и бордер к option. Почему и как это исправить?

```css
.sortvibor {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow 400';
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.sortvibor span {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
}
.sortvibor form {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.sortvibor select {
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow 400';
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 155px;
  padding: 2px 50px 2px 5px;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #467797;
}
.sortvibor option:checked {
  display: none;
}
.sortvibor option:not(:checked) {
  color: #467797;
}
.sortvibor option {
  border: 1px solid #467797;
}
.sortvibor .strelka {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 4px;
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="sortvibor">
  <span>Сортировать:</span>
  <form action="">
    <select name="sort" id="sort">
      <option selected value="">Дешевле</option>
      <option value="">Дороже</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <span class="strelka">&#9660;</span>
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы шрифт и бордер был таким же, как и у всего select. Бордер применяется только к родительскому окну.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`option` css-ом не стилизуются.
Кастомные select стилизуются с помощью js\jquery.
Например так:

```js
// Select
 $('.select').each(function(){
  // Variables
  var $this = $(this),
   selectOption = $this.find('option'),
   selectOptionLength = selectOption.length,
   selectedOption = selectOption.filter(':selected'),
   dur = 500;

  $this.hide();
  // Wrap all in select box
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
  // Style box
  $('<div>',{
   class: 'select__gap',
   text: 'Please select'
  }).insertAfter($this);
  
  var selectGap = $this.next('.select__gap'),
   caret = selectGap.find('.caret');
  // Add ul list
  $('<ul>',{
   class: 'select__list'
  }).insertAfter(selectGap);  

  var selectList = selectGap.next('.select__list');
  // Add li - option items
  for(var i = 0; i < selectOptionLength; i++){
   $('<li>',{
    class: 'select__item',
    html: $('<span>',{
     text: selectOption.eq(i).text()
    })    
   })
   .attr('data-value', selectOption.eq(i).val())
   .appendTo(selectList);
  }
  // Find all items
  var selectItem = selectList.find('li');

  selectList.slideUp(0);
  selectGap.on('click', function(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass('on')){
    $(this).addClass('on');
    selectList.slideDown(dur);

    selectItem.on('click', function(){
     var chooseItem = $(this).data('value');

     $('select').val(chooseItem).attr('selected', 'selected');
     selectGap.text($(this).find('span').text());

     selectList.slideUp(dur);
     selectGap.removeClass('on');
    });
    
   } else {
    $(this).removeClass('on');
    selectList.slideUp(dur);
   }
  });  

 });
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.select {
    display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; 
  max-width: 245px;
    width: 100%;
}

.select-wrap {
 max-width: 700px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 20px auto;
}

.select-wrap select {
 margin: 20px;
}

.select__gap {
 background: transparent;
 color: #467797;
    border: 1px solid #467797;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
}

.on.select__gap,
.select__gap:hover {
  color: #467797;
} 

.select__list {
 background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #467797;
 margin: 0px 0;
}

.select__list.on {
 display: block;
}

.select__item span {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
    color: #333;
}

.select__item.selected,
.select__item span:hover {
 color: #467797;
}

.select__gap:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 15px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -7px;
 border-left: 7px solid transparent;
 border-right: 7px solid transparent;
 border-top: 14px solid #000;

 -webkit-transition: all .27s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all .27s ease-in-out;
         transition: all .27s ease-in-out;

 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
         transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.on.select__gap:after {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
         transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Сортировать:
<select name="select-box" id="selectId" class="select">
  <option value="item-1" name="value">item-1</option>
  <option value="item-2" name="value">item-2</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Изменить стиль таких элементов как select нельзя. Для этого используют либо готовые бибилиотеки js либо пишут свою обертку.

Прячем селект, формируем через дивы, спаны выпадающий список и при кликах на элементы этого списка в спрятаном селекте ставим выбранное значение.

Есть такой плагин для jQuery https://select2.github.io/

Comment: Ну смотри, у него даже в посте это уже не дефолтный селектор. Просто нельзя сделать определенные вещи, часть можно кастомизировать

Comment: У меня дефолтный селектор.