# задать высоту у option

Tags: css

Есть селектбокс следующего вида. Как настроить высоту у option?

height, padding - не работают

```html
<select>
   <option></option>
   <option></option>
   <option></option>
   <option></option>
   <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Нельзя стилизовать option css'ом

Comment: поделитесь тогда пожалуйста, как мне это сделать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564448/Как-стилизовать-option-select

Comment: Хочешь стильный симпатичны крутой офигенный сногсшибательный выпадающий список...???  Пиши свой...